# css/pre:empty with non-empty pre contents

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>foo</TITLE>
<style type="text/css">
pre:empty {
  display: none;
}
</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<PRE>
some text here in the pre
element
</PRE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and I wonder why the browser (safari 5.1) does not display anything. I assumed that the `pre:empty` applies only to empty elements. I'd like to hide `<pre></pre>` tags but none of the pre tags with contents in them.

Comment: it works good at my Safari 5.0.5 i also added some emty pre tags and they are not displayed so it looks good to me

Comment: This will also not work on any MSIE browsers pre IE8, maybe you should use jquery?

Comment: In my environment I can't use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest, try putting it in a style sheet rather that in `<style />`. The reason for this is:

"In Safari versions up to and including 2, when it appears in an internal style sheet (using  tags), this selector will always match. If this selector is used within an external style sheet, it works as designed."

... From (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty)

Now i know you said you're running 5.1, but its worth a try right?

Comment: It was in a stylesheet before. I had a funny experience although I did not track it down: when I load the page, the element is hidden, when I click on the reload button, the element is displayed. - I have this problem in QtAssistant where the element needs to be present right away.